# How to attach the cdkMenu to another dom element instead of body

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-cdk

Is there a way to attach the `cdkMenu` or `cdkOverlay` DOM element to another element than the `<body>`?

In my web application the body is not scrollable, but a child element is. When scrolling the cdkMenu will stick to it's position and won't follow the scroll direction.

Comment: For those who have the same problem:

Meanwhile I found a solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745292/reposition-cdkconnectedoverlay-on-scroll